# Is there really no Cranking Amps formula?

Tags: electromagnetism, batteries

I am looking for an apparently non existent physics formula (see below) so that I can very roughly  (+/- 25%) calculate the Cranking amps (CA) of a SLA (sealed lead acid) battery.  I want to use the listed voltage and listed capacity (in Ah), and a standard operating range for Internal Resistance of SLA batteries.  Which I thought would allow me to use V=IR to calculate CA

BUT …. I must be missing sumpin, cuz

The EE section of Stack exchange had a similar question and the consensus of the electrical engineers was "ya cant calculate CA, there is no formula. you gotta test each battery, cuz there are all sorts of variables like temp, materials, construction, and the SOC (state of charge)".

Here are some actual quotes for the EEs

1. “Rather than a formula you should use graphical analysis”
2. “No such formula exists. “
3. “If you want a formula to calculate the theoretical, temperature dependent CCA of an individual battery it would require extensive differential equations and a very in-depth knowledge of the battery's chemistry, and it would be even more difficult to accurately predict the actual performance of a specific battery, as there are a massive amount of variables that can affect CCA. So no, there is no formula to calculate CCA. It is simply a rating.

I am wondering if the physics community is in agreement.  Cuz as I see it I=V/R must hold so all this talk about variables that are too hard to account for, are all tweaking R.  But R for SLA batteries according to 2 sources is around 20 milliohms and ranges from 5 to 30 milliohms. So can't we just understand that all the variables will create a range for R and use I=V/R to

BUT When I do that, 12V / 20 mOhms = 6000 Amps then I multiply by 30 180,000 Cranking amps. With a range of sec and I get 200 “and a range of 720,000 (at 5 mOhm down to 120,000 amps (at 30 mOhm).  That is clearly wrong.

Maybe we need external resistance, but if so why? External resistance can't determine what a battery’s max Amperage capacity is, can it?

BTW The reason is that I am looking to replace a battery in my dead “portable Car Jump Starter” and while these batteries obviously can jump start cars they don't list the CA in the specs, but I figure if I know V and R within the battery, using I=V/R I can know the max current it can deliver. This seems like yr 1 physics to me … what am I missing

Comment: *”Cuz as I see it I=V/R must hold”* Why?

Comment: *"The EE section of Stack exchange..."*  They're the people to ask.  They'll know way more than the vast majority of physicists will about this.

Comment: Chemomechanics, cuz i thot that was a Law'

Comment: $I=\tfrac{V}{R}$ is the "law" for a resistor; a battery is not resistor although it has an internal resistance, those are not the same thing.

Comment: An ideal battery violates Ohm's law, since it has nonzero voltage at zero current. And then, real batteries violate Ohm's law in much more complicated ways...

Comment: Wow! This is why I am here.  I literally thot that Ohms law was inviolable and applied even outside electronics (in water and air systems as well). Thanks! Now I see how it could make sense that there is no formula to derive CA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I believe the EE Stack Exchange question being referred to is [Calculating CCA of a starter battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/292544/calculating-cca-of-a-starter-battery)—"*I'm searching for some kinda of formula that can be used to calculate the Cold Cranking Amps...of a battery.*" There are some relevant points that can be made from a physics viewpoint here that aren't really covered in that discussion.)

> Cuz as I see it I=V/R must hold so all this talk about variables that are too hard to account for, are all tweaking R.

This isn't the case because **a real battery isn't an [Ohmic device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) or [ideal voltage source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source) or combination of these**. Even at constant current and constant temperature—the conditions of a typical CCA test standard—and during the test itself, the voltage and resistance are varying.

So Ohm's Law with the assumption of a constant voltage is a non-starter (ha ha).

OK, fine. **Where do these two parameters of voltage and resistance come from, and can't we use models to develop formulas for them?**

Various aspects of thermodynamics and kinetics enter here. Broadly, the former looks at states of relative equilibrium, and the latter looks at process rates. The tendency of Nature to equilibrate fields (here, electron levels, voltages) provides the driving force, and mobilities and resistances mediate the resulting flow (here, current).

The voltage arises from a chemical "pressure": [the tendency of lead and lead compounds to sulfate in sulfuric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead%E2%80%93acid_battery). The energy (specifically, the [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy)) of the products is lower than that of the reactants, and so charge carriers in the form of aqueous ions are driven to complete this reaction. We take advantage of this electrochemical driving force by using an equivalent flow of charge carriers in the form of electrons to power a desired load, such as an automobile starter motor.

So one could model the voltage based on the reactants and products. Well, specifically, their identity *and* their concentration. Oh, and one must generally incorporate the temperature, which appears in the Gibbs free energy definition. Oh, and other reactions may be occurring. We end up with about 2 V at room temperature, or 12 V for six cells in series, but we can expect this value to vary depending on the depletion/accumulation/degradation of the constituent materials during discharging, charging, and storage. This already introduces a fairly complex time and history dependence even if the key reaction remains unchanged.

That's the thermodynamics aspect.

The kinetics aspect is arguably even harder to model accurately—prohibitively hard. The reaction rate is dependent on the *local* reactant and product concentrations, which differ from the average values. The rate is dependent on the material geometry and roughness of ever-dissolving and ever-precipitating electrodes. The products of undesired reactions may block the desired reaction from occurring. Ionic transport depends on the concentrations and impurities in the electrolyte, which may be stratified or well mixed. Mechanical stress/strain/fracture may be a factor.

I've had colleagues who wrote a PhD thesis on *one* of the above kinetics nuances for *one* geometry and material type, in a controlled laboratory environment.

Even a single parameter such as the electrode surface roughness—which isn't measurable in the field and can be expected to vary across manufacturer sources—has a strong influence on the electrochemical reaction rates and thus the output current. Now the ever-lengthening formula has to include the history of the manufacturing process and the battery qualification testing and use. This is what it takes to model the effective voltage and resistance accurately, and this is why nobody does it in practice. They instead characterize the capacity with surrogates such as the open-circuit voltage, the density of the electrolyte, and the CCA.

I hope this gives a little more clarity to the physics details behind the lack of a simple, widely used CCA formula.

Comment: That was a thing of beauty! Thank you. You had me at Non Ohmic. I didn't realize that was a thing (which was the basic cause of my analysis going of the rails so fantastically) Oh and ... non starter, the cherry on top.  Still laffing.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formula, but there is a CCA *specification* issued by the SAE (Society of Automotive Engineers). Look up SAE J537.

Comment: Great reference, thank you!